# How to group documents and get the count of documents and also get Avg of sub-documents in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to Group the documents in MongoDB and get the count of it, along with that to get the avg count of subdocuments.

**Collection**

```
[{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "cityName": "Bengaluru",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2085,
            "properties": {
                "countryName": "India",
                "continentName": "Asia"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2085,
            "properties": {
                "countryName": "India",
                "continentName": "Asia"
            }
        }
    ]
}
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "cityName": "Bengaluru",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2095,
            "properties": {
                "countryName": "India",
                "continentName": "Asia"
            }
        }
    ]
}

{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "cityName": "Bengaluru",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2035,
            "properties": {
                "countryName": "India",
                "continentName": "Asia"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "cityName": "Delhi",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2031,
            "properties": {
                "countryName": "India",
                "continentName": "Asia"
            }
        }
                {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2032,
            "properties": {
                "countryName": "India",
                "continentName": "Asia"
            }
        }
    ]
}
...
]
```

**Expected result**

```
[
    {
        "cityName": "Bengaluru",
        "count": 3
        "avgFeatures": 1
    },
    {
        "cityName": "Delhi",
        "count":1
        "avgFeatures": 2
    },
]
```

in the above example `count: 1` groups the data according to the cityName. ex: `db.mycollection.aggregate({$project: { count: { $size:"$features" }}})`.

And avg features nothing but average of `features` array count by all documents grouped by cityName.

Any kind of help will much be appreciated.

Comment: Why  expected`avgFeatures` for `Bengaluru` is `1` instead of `1.33` ?

Comment: please explain what must represent count (and avgFeature)

Comment: `Count` represents group of records ex: 3 `cityName:Bengaluru` objects present. & Avg actually it's 1.33 for bengaluru can we do round figure of it? Avg taken by counting features array count related to grouped objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this gives the exact result you need:

```java
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$cityName",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            },
            "featureCount": {
                "$push": {
                    "$size": "$features"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "cityName": "$_id",
            "count": "$count",
            "avgFeatures": {
                "$round": [{
                    "$divide": [{
                        "$sum": "$featureCount"
                    }, "$count"]
                },0]
            },
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan By executing your solution I got `[{
 "_id" : null,
 "cityName" : null,
 "count" : 2,
 "avgFeatures" : 5
}]` as a result But my expected result is different! can you please check it once. I have Ignored the `$round:[...]` because my mongoDB version won't support it.

Comment: the query works. see here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/S5CDS33oWT_ and i removed the round on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this [Mongo PlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f0syI5ScYI-)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
      $group: {
         _id: "$cityName",
          count: {
                $sum: 1
          },
          sumFeatures: {
                $sum: {
                     $size: "$features"
                }
          }
      }
 },
 {
      $project: {
          _id: 1,
           count: 1,
           avg: {
               $floor: {
                      $divide: [
                                 "$sumFeatures",
                                 "$count"
                               ]
               }
           }
      }
 })
```